# Yield return and method state

Tags: c#, database, .net-4.0, yield-return

I was trying to remove some duplication from my database execution methods. I had a bunch of methods with the following structure:

```
IDbConnection connection = mConnections[pConnectionID];
bool wasAlreadyOpen = connection.State == ConnectionState.Open;

try
{
   if (!wasAlreadyOpen)
      connection.Open();

   using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
      command.CommandText = pSQL;
      if (pParams != null)
         ApplyParameters(pParams, command);
      // do something interesting with command
   }
}
finally
{
   if (!wasAlreadyOpen)
      connection.Close();
}
```

I extracted this logic into another method with this signature:

```
private object ExecuteQuery(int pConnectionID, string pSQL,
   Func<IDbCommand, object> pQuery, IEnumerable<QueryParameter> pParams)
```

and in the `// do something` part of the algorithm, does this:

```
return pQuery(command);
```

This seems to work great, except for one issue. In my `ExecuteReader` method, the query code looks like this:

```
using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
   if (reader != null)
      while (reader.Read())
         yield return reader;
```

The problem seems to be that the "state" that is saved for `yield return` to execute lazily is only taken from the method which contains the `yield` statement. If I extract those four lines above to its own method, or anonymous method/lambda, then there isn't enough state to keep the database connection open while data is being read.

Is there a way to extract this logic the way I am doing this, or am I only left with inlining this particular method and ignoring the duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this is to not lazily load from the database. I have a feeling it's not a good idea to load from a database lazily anyway. Instead I have added to the ExecuteReader method a transform function `Func<IDataRecord, T>` parameter. The data records that are read are then immediately converted into objects, rather than expecting the caller to take an `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>` and do something with it.

I liked the concision of the `yield return` version, but I think ultimately it is better not to lazily load from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

What is the point in returning the same copy of reader again and again ?

**WRONG Logic**

```
using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
   if (reader != null)
      while (reader.Read())
         yield return reader;
```

What you are doing is returning the same DataReader object multiple times.

#### what you need to do is create Class Object from reader object and return the read data.

pseudo-code

```
using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
   if (reader != null)
      while (reader.Read())
      {
           MyObject obj = new MyObject(reader.getInt32(0), reader.getString(1), reader.getFloat(2));
           yield return obj;
      }
```

Comment: reader implements `IDataRecord`. That code returns an `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>`. It works quite well to implement it that way, except for the problem with `yield return`. Your code is essentially what I have done instead, although I no longer use `yield return`, since it would still close the connection before you had created all the objects in the extracted method.

Comment: `The IDataReader and IDataRecord interfaces allow an inheriting class to implement a DataReader class, which provides a means of reading one or more forward-only streams of result sets`, hence you need to return the object not the IDataRecord itself

Comment: But this won't actually fix the problem that the command is disposed too early.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should make your method generic. That is, your method shouldn't return `object`, it should return `T`:

```
private T ExecuteQuery<T>(int pConnectionID, string pSQL,
   Func<IDbCommand, T> pQuery, IEnumerable<QueryParameter> pParams)
```

Now, what I think you should do is to add another overload of `ExecuteQuery` specifically for collections:

```
private IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(int pConnectionID, string pSQL,
   Func<IDbCommand, IEnumerable<T>> pQuery, IEnumerable<QueryParameter> pParams)
```

which would be implemented using `yield return` itself. Something like:

```
using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
   command.CommandText = pSQL;
   if (pParams != null)
      ApplyParameters(pParams, command);

    foreach (var x in pQuery(command))
        yield return x;
}
```

This way, the command will be disposed only after iteration of the result completes (or if it's aborted prematurely).

(I'm not completely sure about this, but there is a chance that overload resolution will pick the wrong overload for collections. In that case, rename the collection version to something like `ExecuteQueryCollection`.)

Comment: The problem is that if that last code block you posted is extracted to its own method, there is not enough state in that method to keep the connection alive. The `yield` mechanism will keep everything in that one method alive, but if the connection is outside that method (in the `ExecuteQuery<T>` method), then the connection will not be kept open, and when you try reading from the `IEnumerable`, you get an exception saying that the connection is already closed.

Comment: @Sahuagin Yeah, you can't just pull that out into its own method. I think the best option here will require some code duplication.